# issue with php basic

Tags: php, html

[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in N:\ftp\compc\ac12mm\Practical 3 Files\myContacts.php on line 102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSHOo.png)

Any Idea what would be wrong with this please?
Please help this is really fustrating me, Im not very good at php

Comment: You're embedding HTML directly in your script file without dropping out of PHP

Comment: how can I correct this please?

Comment: To know for sure, include your source code, though @Mark is probably correct, or you've got an open php tag `<?php` without having closed it off `?>`

Comment: This is my first time using Stackoverflow im not sure how to add the code thats why i added the picture sorry,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I posted an answer. From the image, you're already doing the right things in other parts of your code. You just need to add `echo` like is being done else where.

Comment: Sorry for being anoying but where do I add echo to? @Twisty

Comment: Line 102 if you can't find it.

Comment: I added this to Line 102 but still not working, unexpected end on line 139 </html>

Comment: Follow this link to post ur code on stackoverflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I also see that ur running your php script directly in the browser without any host. use WAMP, XAMPP to run your script.

Comment: I can't see line 139 from your image. I do see line 107 also had the same problem and I suspect some line before 139 starts a new PHP Block and it is never closed, that line 139 is the end of your code I bet. Please follow the guide from @vishalkin

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include HTML Code directly in your PHP code.

To fix, you must use a command like `echo`, `print()`, or break from your PHP Code. This would require a PHP end block:

```
} else {
?>
<TD>
```

Or:

```
} else {
    echo "<TD>";
```

See more: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php